# Using sql, I am trying to show the names of the constraints used over many tables

Tags: sql

Using sql, I am trying to show the names of the constraints used over many tables.

I tried using:

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type FROM user_constraints;
```

And I'm not sure what I'm looking at when the tables show up.

I know that if I add `WHERE table_name = <table name>` that I can get the constraints for a single table, but I was wondering if there is syntax for more than one table?

Comment: If you mean two or more tables, you can use `where table_name = 't1' or table_name = 't2'`, or `where table_name in ('t1', 't2')`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  table_schema, 
  constraint_name, 
  table_name 
from 
  information_schema.table_constraints
```